# Duplicate one array of objects in multiple arrays

Tags: javascript

I want to duplicate one array of objects into multiple ones, because every one of them I need to use in separate places.

```
if(!this.tempLookups){
    for (let count = 0; count < this.dates.length; count++) {
       this.tempLookups[count] = this.lookups[key];
    }
}
```

Error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of null

Comment: `this.tempLookups = []` after the if condition

Comment: Awkward, Pranav,you right! Thank you!

Comment: You can do it in single line without a for loop, like `this.tempLookups = new Array(this.dates.length).fill(this.lookups[key])`

Comment: is `this.lookups[key]` an array?

Comment: If `this.lookups` is array of arrays, than you should use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create shallow copy of `this.lookups[key]` array - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59644110/6231376).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual reason for the error is clearly in error message that you are trying to set the property for a `null`. So in order to fix simply define it after the if.

```
if(!this.tempLookups){
    his.tempLookups = [];
    for (let count = 0; count < this.dates.length; count++) {
       this.tempLookups[count] = this.lookups[key];
    }
}
```

You can do it in a single line without a `for` loop using [`Array#fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) method since you are filling with the same value.

```
if(!this.tempLookups){    
   this.tempLookups = new Array(this.dates.length).fill(this.lookups[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
if (!this.tempLookups) {
    this.tempLookups = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dates.length; i++) {
       this.tempLookups.push(Array.from(this.lookups[key]));
    }
}
```

Note that the `this.tempLookups` variable is initialized as empty array before we start inserting data. The [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) call in `for` loop makes sure we actually create (shallow) copies of the `this.lookups[key]` array, instead of just assigning reference to the same `this.lookups[key]` array multiple times. Without `Array.from` changing one array would change all of them - because in reality there would be only one array referenced multiple times.